# How to change android studio unused field/method color

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, color-scheme

I'm setting up a custom color scheme for android studio. I'm looking to remove the squiggly that is placed under unused methods and fields. But I can't find it anywhere. (it's also not under "language defaults".)

**Does anyone know where I can find it?**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using IntelliJ 2017-

`File | Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General -> Errors and Warnings`

Using IntelliJ 2018+

`File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General -> Errors and Warnings`

Comment: Note: in IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1, you have to go to `File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General ` and then choose the downarrow next to `Errors and Warnings` in the middle view pane.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio 4.*

```
File / Settings... / Editor / Color Scheme / General / Errors & Warnings / Unused Symbol
```

[image: Android Studio settings]